# MVC catch all route passing URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a decent size MVC 4 app that is making heavy use of Areas, plus the basic Home and Account controller.  What I need to do is have a URL pattern that goes to a Controller and passing the rest of the URL.  I've tried just about every combination, but nothing seems to be working.

I created a controller called AutoInController with the following method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string url)
{
    string mes = string.Empty;
    return View();
}
```

And I want to pass any URLs requested, starting with 'AutoIn' to this method with the rest of the url as the parameter.  Here's the route I've tried, along with various others including using constraints.  I'm adding this last, after the default.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Autologin",
   "AutoIn/{*url}",
    new { controller = "AutoIn", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.  It shouldn't be this hard.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to add it **before** the default route.

Answer (score 0):

I tried just about everything and the problem was that I couldn't get it to catch all that prefixed with 'AutoIn', just ALL.

I ended up changing my AccountController to handle this on the Login method to interrogate the URL and then if it was prefixed with 'AutoIn', take appropriate action.

Thanks for the answers.  Routes can be tricky when you want to do some special stuff.